# Android App Crash: Parsing JSON into ListView

Tags: android, json, android-listview, crash, android-asynctask

I posted earlier but am still having the same problem. My android app will load up this activity and then crash before it is able display any of the information from my JSON object. I have no clue why it is. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code for the activity that keeps crashing:

```
public class MainScreen extends ListActivity{
    JSONObject jsonObj= null;

    String[] eventArr= new String[10];
    int i=0;

    String[] urlArr = new String[10];//"http://accomplist.herokuapp.com/api/v1/sharedevent/1/?format=json";

    private static final String TAG_EVENT="event"; //A JSON object within the JSON object that will be returned by JSONParse()
    private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION="description"; //A JSON tag within the JSON object EVENT
    private static String eventString="Yo";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);
        ListView eventsList= getListView();
        for(int b=0; b<urlArr.length; b++) {
            urlArr[b]= "http://accomplist.herokuapp.com/api/v1/sharedevent/"+(b+1)+"/?format=json";
        }
        new JSONParse().execute(urlArr[0]);
    }
private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... jsonurl) {
//        StringBuilder url= new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(jsonurl));
        HttpUriRequest request= new HttpGet("http://accomplist.herokuapp.com/api/v1/sharedevent/2/?format=json");
        HttpResponse r= null;
        try {
            r = client.execute(request);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
        int status= r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (status==200){
            HttpEntity e=r.getEntity();
            String data= null;
            try {
                data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
            try {
                jsonObj = new JSONObject(data);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
            try {
                JSONObject eventJson= jsonObj.getJSONObject(TAG_EVENT);
                eventString= eventJson.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);
            }
            catch (JSONException e1) {
                eventString="Couldn't Parse Data";
            }
            return eventString;
        }
        else{
            return eventString;
        }
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate() {
        Toast loadingToast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loading", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        loadingToast.show();
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        eventString=result;
        eventArr[i]=eventString;
        i++;
        MainScreen.this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainScreen.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,eventArr));

    }
}
}
```

Here is my LogCat Error:

```
com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d11730 that was originally bound here
android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d11730 that was originally bound here
at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-26 19:17:53.381: ERROR/StrictMode(856): null
android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d11730 that was originally bound here
at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-26 19:17:53.381: WARN/ActivityManager(324): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@415528b0
02-26 19:17:53.411: ERROR/ActivityThread(856): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cdc7c0 that was originally bound here
android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cdc7c0 that was originally bound here
at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-26 19:17:53.491: DEBUG/dalvikvm(7047): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
02-26 19:17:53.511: ERROR/StrictMode(856): null
android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cdc7c0 that was originally bound here
at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-26 19:17:53.531: WARN/ActivityManager(324): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@415a58e8
02-26 19:17:53.531: DEBUG/dalvikvm(7047): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
02-26 19:17:53.671: DEBUG/dalvikvm(7047): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
02-26 19:17:53.671: DEBUG/dalvikvm(7047): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
02-26 19:17:53.771: DEBUG/dalvikvm(856): GC_CONCURRENT freed 464K, 19% free 2624K/3216K, paused 21ms+13ms, total 425ms
02-26 19:17:55.471: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(7047): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
02-26 19:17:55.491: DEBUG/dalvikvm(7047): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 157 unimplemented (abstract) methods
02-26 19:17:55.561: INFO/ActivityManager(324): START u0 {flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.Accomplist/.MyActivity} from pid 7047
02-26 19:17:55.621: WARN/WindowManager(324): Failure taking screenshot for (246x437) to layer 21030
02-26 19:17:55.711: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(7047): Shutting down VM
02-26 19:17:55.751: DEBUG/dalvikvm(7060): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
02-26 19:17:55.751: DEBUG/dalvikvm(7047): GC_CONCURRENT freed 91K, 16% free 491K/584K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 43ms
02-26 19:17:55.776: DEBUG/jdwp(7047): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
02-26 19:17:55.776: DEBUG/dalvikvm(7047): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
02-26 19:17:55.832: INFO/ActivityManager(324): Start proc com.example.Accomplist for activity com.example.Accomplist/.MyActivity: pid=7060 uid=10048 gids={50048, 3003, 1028}
02-26 19:17:55.845: INFO/Choreographer(652): Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-26 19:17:56.642: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
02-26 19:17:57.032: ERROR/Trace(7060): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-26 19:17:59.312: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
02-26 19:17:59.552: DEBUG/gralloc_goldfish(7060): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-26 19:17:59.742: DEBUG/dalvikvm(528): GC_EXPLICIT freed 159K, 5% free 5791K/6072K, paused 25ms+35ms, total 331ms
02-26 19:17:59.891: INFO/ActivityManager(324): Displayed com.example.Accomplist/.MyActivity: +4s204ms (total +35s239ms)
02-26 19:18:00.292: INFO/Choreographer(1137): Skipped 116 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-26 19:18:01.021: INFO/Choreographer(652): Skipped 62 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-26 19:18:04.122: INFO/ActivityManager(324): START u0 {act=com.example.Accomplist.MAINSCREEN cmp=com.example.Accomplist/.MainScreen} from pid 7060
02-26 19:18:04.142: WARN/WindowManager(324): Failure taking screenshot for (246x437) to layer 21035
02-26 19:18:05.152: DEBUG/dalvikvm(7060): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 69K, 7% free 2606K/2796K, paused 295ms, total 328ms
02-26 19:18:05.182: INFO/dalvikvm-heap(7060): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.267MB for 635812-byte allocation
02-26 19:18:05.432: DEBUG/dalvikvm(7060): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5K, 6% free 3222K/3420K, paused 249ms, total 249ms
02-26 19:18:05.822: DEBUG/dalvikvm(7060): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 6% free 3234K/3420K, paused 15ms+74ms, total 382ms
02-26 19:18:06.292: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
02-26 19:18:06.331: INFO/Choreographer(7060): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-26 19:18:06.812: INFO/ActivityManager(324): Displayed com.example.Accomplist/.MainScreen: +2s647ms
02-26 19:18:09.561: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(7060): Shutting down VM
02-26 19:18:09.571: WARN/dalvikvm(7060): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
02-26 19:18:09.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7060): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2143)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-26 19:18:09.771: WARN/ActivityManager(324): Force finishing activity com.example.Accomplist/.MainScreen
02-26 19:18:09.922: WARN/WindowManager(324): Failure taking screenshot for (246x437) to layer 21040
02-26 19:18:10.271: INFO/Choreographer(324): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-26 19:18:10.281: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
02-26 19:18:10.499: WARN/ActivityManager(324): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{40da7188 u0 com.example.Accomplist/.MainScreen}
02-26 19:18:19.976: WARN/ActivityManager(324): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
02-26 19:18:20.776: WARN/ActivityManager(324): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{40d319a

0 u0 com.example.Accomplist/.MyActivity}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are `NullPointerException` exception because you are not adding 10 items inside Array currently u are adding only one item in `eventArr` Array but Array size is 10 .

suggestion use ArrayList instead of Array if items are dynamic size in ArrayList. change your code as :

declare ArrayList in place of Array :

```
ArrayList<String> eventArr=new ArrayList<String>();
```

and inside `onPostExecute` or `doInBackground` method of AsyncTask add json items to ArrayList then set ArrayList as datasoucre for Adapter:

```
  @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        eventString=result;

        eventArr.add(result);  //<< add item to ArrayList

        MainScreen.this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainScreen.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,eventArr));

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, This actually proved to be the solution! Your help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @sourdesi : most welcome friend can u make it as answer if this help u in solving current issue .Thanks